# php Object stored in APC drops mySQL link

Tags: php, mysql, class, apc

I cant really provide the exact code so I'll do my best to illustrate the issue.  First I have a couple of DB connections that connect and work just fine ($local, $remote).  I'm passing those connections into a class called dbReader, storing them in the object and finally storing the object in APC:

```
class dbReader {

public $APC;
public $local;//Local DB
public $remote;//Remote DB

public function __construct($local,$remote){
    ePrint($IMX);
    $this->APC = new CacheAPC();//APC Object
    $this->local = $local;
    $this->remote = $remote;

    //Store dbreader in APC for reference:
    $this->storeDBReader();
}
public function getRunTypes(){
    //Query APC:
    $array = $this->APC->getData('RunTypes');
    //Populate APC:
    if(!$array){
        $array = array();
        $query = ...;

        $result = mysql_query($query,$this->remote);
        while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $array[$row['ID']] = $row['Val'];
        }
        $this->APC->setData('RunTypes',$array);
    }
    return $array;
}

public function storeDBReader(){
    //Store dbReader in APC for reference:
    $this->APC->setData('dbReader',$this);
}
```

}

The connection link is good all throughout the process, until I recover the dbReader object from APC and try to call the getRunTypes() function.  I'm thinking that the when the object is store in the APC, the mySQL links are destroyed.  Is this true?  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't store connections in APC - you need to re-establish the link.

Comment: Generally speaking you're meant to disconnect before you serialize and put something in the cache, and then re-connect when you pull something out of the cache and deserialize it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Erik, if you want to answer with your comment, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't serialize the resource, and storing in APC automatically serializes objects.

This is what the magic methods [__sleep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) and [__wakeup()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) are for: they are basically pre-serialize and post unserialize hooks that you can use to unset and reset the database connection when you store and then retrieve the object from apc.

Comment: Good to know, I'll cetainly keep this in mind for future applications.  For now I'm just going to store the connections in $GLOBALS, I know that's sacrilegious, but it works, requires less code and has no downside in this instance.